# How to know our application is active or idle?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, timeout, user-interaction

I want to set auto timeout scenario in my application after "x" mins. I tried with timer call using schedule timer (after "x" mins). User is reading a T&C page with scrollable/tap state also timer is triggered. But I'm expecting timer call when user doesn't do any action(touch, scroll). simply if user doesn't touch the screen for specified period of time, I need to call timeout popup. I want to handle this timeout scenario for my entire application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` on `UIWindow` which receives touches on screen.
Here i have added timer for 5 second after that timeOut function will call.

Add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in `Appdelegate`

```
   var window: UIWindow?
    var timer: Timer?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
       //Start timer for first time
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timeOut), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        print(" tapped on screen,")
        timer?.invalidate()
        //set Timer Ex: 5 Second
        //Run timer on touch
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        return false
    }
    @objc func timeOut() {
        print("TimeOut")
    }
```

Comment: It Works with tableView scroll, Tap, UItextView Scroll, label tap, button tap, all the objects on `UIWindow` :)